# Batch Script Error - unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, batch-file

I'm trying to run a task where I have a script that will add a user to a remote server via ssh.

Here is my code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set username=%1
set password=%2
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (Linuxhosts.txt) do (
    ssh -i svcaccount_id_rsa svcaccount@%%a 'bash -s' < adduser.txt
)
```

Here are the contents of the adduser.txt file

```
#!/bin/bash
#========================================================================================================
# This script allows for account creation on a server                           |
# It also performs error handling to ensure that the user doesn't currently exist on the system.    |
# Also provides feedback from the input to verify the entries are correct.              |
#========================================================================================================
while true; do
    echo -n "Enter username: "
    read -r username
    /bin/egrep -i "^${username}:" /etc/passwd
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "User $username already exists. Please check the username and try again."
    else
        echo "User $username does not exist. Proceed with account creation."
        break
    fi
done

adduser "$username"
if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Error encountered."
    exit 1
fi

echo -n "Enter password: "
read -r -s password
echo "$username:$password" | chpasswd
echo "Password was succesfully set for $username."
if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Error encountered. There was a problem with your entry. Please re-run the script and try again."
    exit 1
fi

usermod -a -G wheel "$username"
echo "User was succesfully added to the group wheel."
if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Error encountered."
    exit 1
fi
echo "Successfully added $username to the system."
```

However, when I try to run the first set of code through a cmd prompt, I get the following error:

> bash: line 41: syntax error: unexpected end of file

I'm not sure what I'm missing. I have tested it with another file called hello.txt and it ran fine so I'm wondering if maybe there's spacing issues somewhere that I can't see because it's a text file.

Comment: What happens if you put a newline at the end of the file?

Comment: Still having the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: I keep counting the lines in your bash script and I only come up with 40.

Comment: @Squashman,

Exactly. That's why I'm going "uhhh" at this batch file error.

Comment: Not an aswer to your question, but the last two `if [ $? -gt 0 ]` probably don't do what you expect. `$?` is the exit status of the *last* command. Since you have an `echo` directly before the `if`, `$?` will practically always be 0.

Comment: @Socowi - While that may be the case in other circumstances, I have tested this where a user already existed and it exited out properly with no issues.

Comment: This is _not_ a "Batch Script Error", but a "Bash" one. I strongly suggest you to edit the question title...

Comment: So when you manually logon to the server and run the script does it execute correctly?

Comment: @Aacini while it's _technically_ coming from **bash** the error code is output from the cmd which is leading me to believe it's the error with the _batch_ file I created to run this script written in bash. When the bash is ran standalone, it works flawlessly, when combined into this _batch_ program, it fails. Hence. Batch. Error.

Comment: @Squashman - yes it does. It works beautifully, as designed.

Comment: Does adduser.txt all end in Line Feeds only. No Carriage Returns.

Comment: You error is definitely coming from your script.  It tells you that plain as day. **bash: line 41: syntax error: unexpected end of file**.  The BASH interpreter is throwing that error.  CMD.exe would never in a million years throw that error.

Comment: There is no way that a Batch Script show "unexpected end of file" error, so how do you try to fix a non-existent error? When you say that _"When the bash is ran standalone it works flawlessly"_ do you run it via a command-line like this one: `ssh -i svcaccount_id_rsa svcaccount@XYZ 'bash -s' < adduser.txt`?. If this line show the error, then it comes from the execution of `ssh.exe` program, NOT from any Batch file (because there is _not_ any Batch file here).

Comment: Have you tried replacing the contents of adduser.txt with something dead simple? (`echo "foobar"`)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the immediate problem here is that the file adduser.txt is in DOS/Windows format, with its lines terminated with a carriage return character, followed by a linefeed. Unix (including bash) expects just a linefeed as the line terminator, and hence treats the carriage return as part of the line's text. In this case, that means that bash sees line 17, "done", as "done[carriage return]" which isn't a valid keyword and does not end the `while` loop, so it keeps looking for the "done" keyword... until it runs out of file.

(Credit to Squashman for suggesting this in a comment.)

You're likely to have this problem a lot transferring files from Windows to unix; unfortunately, the tools available to fix the problem vary quite a bit depending on what OS you're using, etc.

BTW, I see a couple of other problems here. For one thing, the `read` commands in the script are going to be trying to read from the same source that bash is reading commands from, which is the adduser.txt file. So when it does e.g. `read -r username` it's actually going to be reading some later line from the script file, not from the user running the batch script. This is going to be very hard to solve the way you're doing it; I think it'll be much better to actually copy the script file to the unix system, then run it separately.

Also, as Socowi pointed out in the comments, `$?` gets the exit status of the *last command executed*, so in sections like this:

```
echo "$username:$password" | chpasswd
echo "Password was succesfully set for $username."
if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
    ...
```

the `if` condition is checks the exit status of the command `echo "Password was succesfully set for $username."`, not the `chpasswd` command. The same problem applies to the `usermod` command later. The better way to do this is to use the command you want to check for success directly as the `if` condition:

```
if echo "$username:$password" | chpasswd; then
    echo "Password was succesfully set for $username."
else
    echo "Error encountered. There was a problem with your entry. Please re-run the script and try again."
    exit 1
fi
```

I'd use this same format in all of the places you're checking exit status: the `egrep`, `useradd`, `chpasswd`, and `usermod` commands.

[UPDATE] After a bit of mulling, I have a couple of possible solutions: First, to fix the carriage return problem, you could pipe the file through `tr -d "\r"` as a quick-n-dirty CR remover (although you may have to play around with the quoting and/or escaping to get that `\r` through both batch and bash's command processing). Second, pass the username and password as arguments to the script instead of having it read them. Thus, your batch script would use something like this:

```
ssh -i svcaccount_id_rsa svcaccount@%%a 'tr -d "\r" | bash -s "username" "password"' < adduser.txt
```

... then change adduser.txt to use `username="$1"; password="$2"` instead of the `read` commands (and also changing that `while` loop into an `if`, since there wouldn't be an option to try again with a different username).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write all of this out. Normally I would say that yes, putting the script on the box and running it from the box would make the most sense. 

However, we are trying to avoid that. Let's say for example the person who wrote the code leaves and they need to update it for whatever reason, if it's on all of the servers which amounts to about 40 different boxes. Which means they would need to update it 40 times. So they've opted to, instead, use a central repository, which happens to be a windows based share on a server.

Comment: @ladycoder2098 I've added some suggestions for working around the problems.

Comment: I did try the updated code piece and I'm finding that it's still giving me errors. But I'm going to try editing it a bit and see if it will work.